# How to give effects on a listview?

Tags: android, android-listview

I need to design a listview like the one in this image without the icon images and the same effects (blading effect). How can I achieve that?

[image]

Comment: using shapedrawable  and gradient you can do this

Comment: are you searching only for effects on items ?

Comment: @RohitGoswami yes I am looking only for applying effects

Comment: http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/04/android-listview-animation.html try this....

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/ - use this link that you want